# Is there a way to add white space in a string based on the array length it is in

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array of items, each item is an array which is a concat of strings and numbers. The result I am looking for is equal to 30 char for each array based white space which hopefully can be automatically added in. Please have a look at the code below

I tried to manually add the white space but my issues is I can not count the char of each array.

```
let data = [
      { Name: 'Cafe Latte', Count: 2, Price: 4.75 },
      { Name: 'Americano', Count: 4, Price: 3.75 }
    ];

   let formattedData = [
      ['Cafe Latte' + 'white space' + 2 + ' x ' + 4.75],
      ['Americano' + 'white space' + 4 + ' x ' + 3.75]
   ];
```

the expected is that the white space is added to sum the length of the array to 30 char.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why does it literally say `'white space'`? Can you show an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: to indicate where the white space it. that is the part that I want to be auto calculated and the white space added to total up the array length to 30 char

Comment: You're probably looking for [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) and [padEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd)

Comment: maybe I'll have a look, thank you

Comment: `equal to 30 char for each array based white space` <- Not sure what you mean here. So you want a whitespace for every 30 characters on the name property strings or something?

Comment: Be careful with that "Price" -- those are floating point numbers, and if you do any arithmetic using them, then want to display the result, you might have weirdness (for example, `0.1 + 0.2 !== 0.3` in JS). If you do have to display results nicely, take a look into the `Numeral` library and just run your result through a formatting step before displaying it to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a function and hand over the left and right part of the string and get a combined string with spaces.

```js
function pad(left, right, size) {
    left = left.toString();
    right = right.toString();
    return left + ''.padStart(size - left.length - right.length) + right;
}


let formattedData = [['Cafe Latte', 2 + ' x ' + 4.75], ['Americano', 4 + ' x ' + 3.75]],
    result = formattedData.map(a => pad(...a, 30));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking for, you want to use either [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) or [`padEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) to create the necessary whitespace.

Here is an example using `padEnd`:

```js
let data = [
  { Name: 'Cafe Latte', Count: 2, Price: 4.75 },
  { Name: 'Americano', Count: 4, Price: 3.75 }
]

let output = data.map(item => {
  let info = `${item.Count} x ${item.Price}`
  let paddedName = item.Name.padEnd(30 - info.length)
  return paddedName + info
})

console.log(output)
```

The important part is that it creates the `Count/Price` part of the string and subtracts its length from your 30 character size limit. The result of that is how much space you need to fill. `padEnd` then adds the required whitespace to `Name`. The two strings are then concatenated and returned for the result.

Note that if your `Name` and/or the string resulting from the `Count/Price` are too long then there will not be any whitespace.